# Stack Overflow Exception in Making Post Call to API Method in MVC5 Through Jquery

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc-5

I am getting stackoverflowexception when i am passing a model to webapi method in MVC

Here is the Model in C#:

```
public class Cartoon
{
    public long Id { get; set; }

    public string Title { get; set; }

    public string ImageURL { get; set; }

    public DateTime? PublishedDateTime { get; set; }
}
```

This is the method in my baseapicontroller which tends to retrun something after getting data:

```
 [AcceptVerbs("GET", "POST")]
    public bool StoreCartoon1(Cartoon cartoon)
    {
        try
        {

            return true;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            throw e;
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Ajax Call:

```
var cartoonModel = new Object();
    cartoonModel.Id = "1";
    cartoonModel.Title = "Sourabh";
    cartoonModel.ImageURL = "/something.jpg";
    var URL = '/api/testApi/StoreCartoon1';
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "json",
        url: URL,
        data: cartoonModel,
        success: function (data) { ShowStatusBar('cartoon added successfully'); },
        error: function (a, b, c) {
           // alert('error ' + a.responseText + '  ' + b + '  ' + c);
            //hideLoadingImage();
            //jsonValue = jQuery.parseJSON(error.responseText);
            //jError('An error has occurred while saving the new part source: ' + jsonValue, { TimeShown: 3000 });
        }
    });
```

Comment: instead of `data: cartoonModel` try `data: { cartoon : cartoonModel }`

Comment: Try with `data: JSON.stringify(cartoonModel)`

Comment: @SaurabhSashank please mark the question as closed if you got your answer